# Mouse move event if mouse down happened

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

How I can use mouse move event when mouse down event happened and when mouse up event I don't want to use mouse move event? I want draw line on canvas in this way.
Please help me?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/  https://api.jquery.com/mouseup/

Comment: Something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/afskwcud/)**?

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the `.mousedown()` event is triggered, bind both the `.mousemove()` and `.mouseup()` events. In the `.mouseup()` event unbind both the `.mouseup()` and `.mousemove()` events. This way the `.mousemove()` will only ever happen when the `.mousedown()` is triggered.

You can try the following example:

CSS

```
#mouse-down-container {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="mouse-down-container"> <span id="mouse-text">mouse is not down or moving</span>

</div>
```

Javascript

```
$("#mouse-down-container").mousedown(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#mouse-text").html("mouse is down");

    $this.mousemove(function () {
         $("#mouse-text").html("mouse is moving");
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function () {
        $("#mouse-text").html("mouse is not down or moving");
        $(document).unbind("mouseup");
        $this.unbind("mousemove");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/csc6e22x/2/

Here's an example of drawing a line on a canvas:
http://jsfiddle.net/hzNg4/7/

Comment: why mouseup and mousemove in the mousedown body, Can I treat with mousemove and mouseup like function out of mousedown?

Comment: The reason for this is so that the mousemove and mouseup events are only ever triggered when the mouse is down. You will notice that the mousup event unbinds those two events again. So basically the two events will only exist when they are needed. Check the example - http://jsfiddle.net/csc6e22x/2/

Comment: I create a canvas on my body and now I want create line with mousedown and mouseup, How I can do?

Comment: Take a look at the bottom of the updated answer http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/hzNg4/

Comment: I want when mouse up also this line is destroyed! thanks

Comment: I want draw line like this on canvas?

Comment: @FardadA what do you mean? The example draws a line on a <canvas> element? Please be more specific as the last example does what you are asking for

Comment: this url: http://codecanyon.net/item/word-search-game/full_screen_preview/2708856.  M.r @jako thank u for your helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that may help you:

```
var _mouseDown = false;
$(".el").mousedown(function() {
    _mouseDown = true;
});
$(".el").mousemove(function() {
    if ( _mouseDown ) {
        console.log("move me");
    } 
});
$(".el").mouseup(function() {
    _mouseDown = false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v4btgen2/

Comment: Mouse move event if mouse down happen.

Comment: If there is a mousedown event, you want to use mousemove?

Comment: If you see this example you understand my question: http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/afskwcud/

Comment: you have to do mousedown and mousemove and then mouseup!
Like a drag

Answer (score 0):

You may create a global variable `drawing` that becomes `true` on mouse down and becomes `false` on mouse up. Then, on mouse move, only draw if `drawing == true`.